# How can I deal with a reaaally large string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm writing a program to search 10 million digits of pi for a specific number. I know there are programs out there to generate pi, but I'd rather search pregenerated pi digits for the number I need. I'm using CodePen, and although I've successfully copy pasted 10 million digits into the editor, it makes things really slow and clunky. Is there a way I can refer to the 10 million digits without actually copy pasting them?

```
var letters = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
$('#letters-and-numbers-wrapper').hide()
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  $('#background').append('<p class="background">x</p>')
}
// eventually make this whenever a letter is typed in the box
$('#search').keyup(function(){
  var query = $('#search').val()
query = query.toLowerCase();
  $('#rowTop').empty()
  $('#rowBottom').empty()
  $('#pi-img-wrapper').slideUp("slow").delay(1000)
   $('#letters-and-numbers-wrapper').slideDown("slow")
  for (var x = 0; x < query.length; x++) {
    $('#rowTop').append('<td class="top sequence">' + query[x] + '</td>')
    num = letters.indexOf(query[x])
    $('#rowBottom').append('<td class="bottom sequence">' + num + '</td>')
  }
});
var searchPi = function(numbers) {

}
```

http://codepen.io/Random_Pseudonym/pen/EWvdge

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Load them from a file instead of putting them right into your program?

Comment: you need to look at the node stream api: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html
and use this in conjunction with fs module.

Comment: What do you mean by "search 10 million digits of pi for a specific number."?

Comment: Yeah, what Bergi said

Comment: In codePen you can create another pen and then reference the URL to it using JS and load it as JSON into another pen. Example here where I am loading in 104,000 digits of PI http://codepen.io/creativekinetix/pen/RpjjJK

Comment: Also, as maxwell suggested, though codePen won't allow the streaming, you could split the files up into chunks so you aren't loading all the digits at once. Play around with that to see how performance is effected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codePen you can create another pen and then reference the URL to it using JS and load it as JSON into another pen. Example here where I am loading in 104,000 digits of PI codepen.io/creativekinetix/pen/RpjjJK

Also, as maxwell suggested, though codePen won't allow the streaming, you could split the files up into chunks so you aren't loading all the digits at once. Play around with that to see how performance is effected.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey, dunno if you're interested but I managed to finish a rough draft of my project thanks to your help. Type in a word and it'll search for the numerical equivalent in pi: http://codepen.io/Random_Pseudonym/pen/EWvdge

Comment: Nice work. Happy I could help out. In your jsonLoaded() you can get rid of line 27 and just add the toString() to the end of data.pi

Comment: Also, if you found my answer helpful, would you mind accepting it as the correct answer? Happy coding.

Comment: Right, sorry. Haven't used stackoverflow much!